# No module named pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Why won't this work? The best solution I could find is that the name of my game can't be `pygame` and I changed the name, yet it still doesn't work. I'm getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dnw13\Desktop\Python projects and notes\pygame games.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame, sys
  File "C:\Users\dnw13\Desktop\Python projects and notes\pygame.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pygame.locals import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame.locals'; 'pygame' is not a package
```

here is my code

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
pygame.display.set_caption('Hello World!')
while True: # main game loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
            pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: can you tell us what is happening (error messages, etc) when you try to run your code?

Comment: Provide a more complete error description than "won't work". What did you want to happen, and what visibly goes wrong? Do you get an error message? If so, post the exact, complete error message.

Comment: ok, will provide the error message that appears

Comment: it seems like you have to install pygame first

Comment: ok, where would i get it from

Comment: @Monkeybike123, Google will help you here. Try `pip install pygame`.

Comment: do you have `pip` installed in your machine? If so, it is as simple as running `pip install pygame`

Comment: what is "pip" ?

Comment: You've still got something named ``pygame`` in your "Python projects and notes" folder, which is being found before the real pygame (whether or not you actually have it installed).  Make sure none of pygame.py, pygame.pyc, or pygame.pyo exist there.

Comment: thanks removed that BUT it still wont work, the error message is "No module named 'pygame' "

Comment: Yeah, in addition to the `pygame.py` name problem, you *also* haven't installed pygame, and you need to install it.

Comment: You can download the pygame module from http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml

Comment: I now have pygame and it still won't work

Comment: Follow one of the methods I provided

Answer (score 3):

First off, if you're going to use a library called pygame, you shouldn't also have a .py file named `pygame.py` in your working directory. Second, pygame, unlike tkinter, is not pre-installed the way tkinter was. You will need to install it separately using one of the following methods:

1st way, using pip:

```
# in the console (Terminal or cmd) depending on your OS, type:
# for windows: (replace 3 with 2 if using python 2)
py -3 -m pip install pygame
# or: (just pip for python 2)
pip3 install pygame

# for Debian: (Mac OS or Unix or Linux etc.)
pip3 install pygame
# just pip for python 2
# or: (replace 3 with 2 for python 2)
python3 -m install pygame
```

2nd way, from pre-compiled file:

Go to the [official download page](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml). And choose your operating system to download the file. You can also follow the [official installation tutorial page.](http://www.pygame.org/install.html)

3rd way, build from source:

Follow the same method from the second method and choose the source files. Then do `./configure` then `make && make install` in the console. This method is not recommended.

Comment: I ran the code above and is doesn't recognize "pip"

Comment: Which one did you run? What's your full error traceback? What's your OS? And lastly, which python version?

Comment: i ran the top one in the idle editor, it won't run as "pip" is a invalid syntax and my OS is windows 64 bit, but i am using python 3.6 32 bit

Comment: Run it in cmd for windows(which is what I said in the comments) I would recommend you running this: `py -3 -m pip install pygame`

Comment: what is cmd for windows (i am newish to python)

Comment: i get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00003da8 (most recent call first):

Comment: That shouldn't happen...are you using a venv?

Comment: If so, disable it first. if not, click [here](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads/pygame-1.9.2a0-hg_8d9e6a1f2635+.win-amd64-py3.4.msi) to download it and double click and finish the installation process

Comment: Read the [instructions](http://www.pygame.org/install.html) for more help

Comment: i get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

Comment: And you sure the installation process succeeded?

Comment: yes it installed correctly, does it matter where i save it?

Comment: Great that's nice. :)

Answer (score -1):

If you work in Windows (I solved it in Win 10), look at global variables:

- search for System Info
- choose button Environment Variables...
- look at the **Path** variable to see if Python has the right path
- if not change it :)
- if necessary - restart programm(s)

It happens when you have multiple versions of Python installed

Comment: This question was answered in the other answer despite the author not yet having marked it as accepted solution.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure pygame is added to the correct path. It installed pygame in the wrong place and python couldn't find it. It took it from where it had installed it (it tells you were this is when you install it.) and dragged it into where i save my games and it now works.

Comment: Please do not write a separate answer if the question has being solved a month ago by answer SO user, this is not fair for him and everyone who provided support, plus, this answer does not even answer the question, so if further users view this post, they will see this incorrect information first. This answer should be deleted.

Comment: OK... this answer actual worked for me as pygame wasn't added to the correct path.

Comment: Maybe add some details on how you fixed it then. This isn't a helpful answer to other users who came here because they had the same problem as you.